# "I assess the quality of software" or "I assess the software quality"

Tags: word-usage

I have one doubt about this phase:

"I assess the quality of software" or "I assess the software quality"

Which one is the correct?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do we say **Police Departament** instead of **Departament of Police**?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/119369/why-do-we-say-police-departament-instead-of-departament-of-police) Also [Putting a noun **before** another noun, or **after** with “**of**” in between?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/100826/putting-a-noun-before-another-noun-or-after-with-of-in-between)

Answer (score 1):

You can go with either order, but in the second version you'd say "I asses software quality" (i.e. no "the"), if you are talking about your job description.